# Android UI Layout Different sizes

Tags: android

To support multiple screen sizes I should have layouts in layout-small, layout-normal, and layout-large. If there is for example a main layout in large but not in the normal folder, will a normal screen size phone default to the layout in the large folder? Is this true for drawable also?

Comment: You should include a res\layout\increase-accept-rate.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the **defaults** in `res/drawable/` and `res/layout`, and put your **size specific values** e.g. in `res/layout-large` or `res/drawable-hdmi`

Here is the link with the instructions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources